# Is There a Command Analogous to \addtocontents{toc}{text} for an Index?

Tags: formatting, indexing, imakeidx, idxlayout

I would like to be able to add a comment to an Index.

For example, say I have the index:

[image]

produced by the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Sentence.\index{Heading@!indice1}\index{Heading@!indice2}
\newpage \index{Heading@!indice3}

\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

But I would like to produce something like this:

[image]

Is there are way to add a comment to a particular place in the Index?

Is there a Latex command similar to \addtocontents for an Index?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the the actual comment going to be?  There are ways to get "index4, see index1".  Or are you wanting capital letters to set off the various portions of the index?  Or do you have categories of items?  Or something else?

Comment: I would like to be able to accomplish this in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\def\kkk#1#2#3{#1}
\begin{document}
\index{Heading@!indice2b@\kkk{\textbf{hello I am a comment}}}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Sentence.\index{Heading@!indice1}\index{Heading@!indice2}
\newpage \index{Heading@!indice3}

\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```