# TeX Definition to Suppress Page Number Conflicting with Macro to Make Other Page Numbers Bold

Tags: macros, indexing, bold, comments, makeindex

In the post [Is There a Command Analogous to \addtocontents{toc}{text} for an Index?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/580746/is-there-a-command-analogous-to-addtocontentstoctext-for-an-index/580761#580761), I inquired as to the existence of a command that could be used to add a comment to the Index in a manner analogous to the way one may add a comment to a TOC.

A very useful answer was provided by David Carlisle which was focused on the use of:

`\def\kkk#1#2#3{#1}`

Recently, I encountered a problem which seems to stem from simultaneously attempting to make the citation pages in the Index bold.

Consider the MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage 

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\def\kkk#1#2#3{#1}

% Make all page numbers in index bold
\let\oldindex\index
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{%
  \oldindex{#1|textbf}%
}%

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE


Sentence.
\index{Heading@!Index entry 1}
\index{Heading@!Index entry 2}
\index{Heading@!Index entry 3}\index{CLASS INTRODUCTION@\kkk{\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{CLASS INTRODUCTION}}}}

\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

which produces the Index

[image]

QUESTION: Can anyone identify what might be causing the problem here and how to correct it so that the MWE produces bold pages where needed and the blue introductory comment as desired?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\gobblethree` at the stage of processing the .ind-file for removing the comma, the token `\textbf` and the page-number which is nested in curly braces.

To make sure that `\gobblethree` is not executed at the time of writing the .idx-file already but makes it into the .ind-file you can prevent its expansion

- by preceding with `\protect`, i.e., `\protect\gobblethree`,
- or by defining `\gobblethree` in terms of `\DeclareRobustCommand`,
- or -- if the LaTeX 2e-kernel is recent enough -- by defining `\gobblethree` in terms of `\newcomand` and afterwards applying `\MakeRobust\gobblethree`.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage 

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\DeclareRobustCommand\gobblethree[3]{}%
%\newcommand\gobblethree[3]{}%
%\MakeRobust\gobblethree

% Make all page numbers in index bold
\let\oldindex\index
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{%
  \oldindex{#1|textbf}%
}%

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE


Sentence.
\index{Heading!Index entry 1}
\index{Heading!Index entry 2}
\index{Heading!Index entry 3}
\index{CLASS INTRODUCTION@\textbf{\protect\textcolor{blue}{CLASS INTRODUCTION}}\gobblethree}

\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

the resulting **.idx**-file:

```
\indexentry{Heading!Index entry 1|textbf}{1}
\indexentry{Heading!Index entry 2|textbf}{1}
\indexentry{Heading!Index entry 3|textbf}{1}
\indexentry{CLASS INTRODUCTION@\textbf  {\textcolor {blue}{CLASS INTRODUCTION}}\gobblethree  |textbf}{1}
```

the resulting **.ind**-file:

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item \textbf  {\textcolor {blue}{CLASS INTRODUCTION}}\gobblethree  , 
        \textbf{1}

  \indexspace

  \item Heading
    \subitem Index entry 1, \textbf{1}
    \subitem Index entry 2, \textbf{1}
    \subitem Index entry 3, \textbf{1}

\end{theindex}
```

the resulting output-file:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting this. However, when I run it with pdflatex, I get an error message because of `\MakeRobust\gobblethree`. When I comment out that command, the program runs fine, but the output looks like the output I originally posted. Do have any idea what might be the problem on my end?

Comment: @mlchristians Probably the LaTeX-kernel used by you not recent enough to contain `\MakeRobust`. Instead of `\newcommand\gobblethree[3]{}\MakeRobust\gobblethree` try `\DeclareRobustCommand\gobblethree[3]{}`. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @mlchristians If all else fails try `\newcommand\gobblethree[3]{}`...`\index{CLASS INTRODUCTION@\textbf{\protect\textcolor{blue}{CLASS INTRODUCTION}}\protect\gobblethree}`, i.e., `\gobblethree` preceded by `\protect`.

Comment: Many thanks! Your revised code works for me.  Thank you for the excellent answer.